# Apple App Store: Are password protected apps allowed?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I want my app to be be usable by only selected audience. Hence I want to password protect my app so that when iphone users download the app and open the app for the first time, they are prompted for the password (this is to make sure only the selected audience will be able to get to main screen of my app).

Does Apple approve my app (in app store and testflight), if I password protect my app(app is written using swift 3)

Comment: I think you'll be OK as long as you give the apple tester some credentials to use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  and/or the store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A company I used to work for did exactly that. You could launch the app, were presented with a login, or given a link to contact the company to become a customer to gain access.

In Itunes Connect, you will see the following section for your app. Here, you must provide a test account that the Apple reviewer can use to properly test your app. There is also a section next to it called notes where you can include information on what a user may do once in the protected area.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "provide an account during submission"? Can we submit an app as anonymous or random name to hide my identity(I thought we should submit from apple developer account)

Comment: @kashili He means you have to provide an account (user name and password) that can be used to log in the App that you are submitting.